# In PowerShell, how can I convert environment variables (like $SystemRoot$) if they are part of a string?

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, registry, environment-variables

I'm trying to write a script which reads file paths from a set of registry keys, but these paths have environment variables like %SystemRoot% in. I know you can usually look up the value of these using:

```
$env:SystemRoot
```

for example. However, if PS receives a string such as "%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\DebugChannel.etl", how can this get converted to the full path I need, i.e. "C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\DebugChannel.etl"?

I've tried using a regex -replace to convert the %% format to the $env: format:

```
$_.FileName -replace "%(\w*)%\\", "`$env:`${1}\"
```

But this just results in the string:

```
$env:SystemRoot\System32\Winevt\Logs\DebugChannel.etl
```

And I'm not sure how to get PowerShell to actually evaluate the "$env:SystemRoot" part. I presume there is a more sensible way of doing this anyway!

The full code I'm using to get the registry values and produce the above result is

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WMI\Autologger | Get-ItemProperty -Name "FileName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | foreach { if($_.FileName) { $_.FileName -replace "%(\w*)%\\", "`$env:`${1}\" } }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using .net. Try this:

```
 [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\DebugChannel.etl")
```

Comment: yes ... and how do I use this ? like in `mv x y` ?